# WCF and MsmqBinding to remote private queue

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

We have a WCF log service that uses MsmqBinding and WAS.  The issue is that I try to use it from remote computer and that message seems to never reach the destination queue.  Here are the facts :

1. Server config

   - List item
   - destination machine name : logserver.domain.ext
   - destination queue : private$/logservice.svc (journaling enabled)
   - security on the queue : everyone : full control, NETWORK SERVICE : Full Control
   - IgnoreOSNameValidation registry key : set
2. Client config

   - client endpoint address : logserver.domain.ext/private/logservice.svc
3. Observed behaviour

   - the output queue is well created ans has status Connected and 0 message wainting
   - if I pause the output queue, I see messages appearing and then desapearing when resume the queue
   - no message can be seen in the remote queue or the journal

and the worth is :

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:logserver.domain.ext\private$\logservice.svc");
queue.Send("hello");
```

works !

Comment: Are you using Server 2008? Are the service and the consumer machines in the same domain?

Comment: @Hugh : Windows 7 to Windows Server 2008 in the same domain.

Comment: Try adding the ANONYMOUS user to your queue permissions (with full control).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not mention permissions for the ANONYMOUS LOGON account. This is the account that remote private queue access will happen under if you are not explicitly using Windows security on the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and it turned out that the issue was with Distributed Transaction Coordinator configuration. [This MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700128(v=vs.85).aspx) helped me solve it.